# How do I use webdriver with imported functions?

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium

I have a function that opens up a webdriver session and then calls for external functions based on the input url.

```
from externalfunctions import *

def itemiser(url):
regex = re.compile(r'www.(.+).com')
name = regex.search(url).group(1)
options = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
    'c': c
}

if name in options:
    ff = webdriver.Firefox()
    ff.get(url)
    result = options[name]()
    ff.quit()
    print(result)
    return result
```

functions a,b,c are in externalfuntions.py

```
def a():
    x = ff.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
    return x
def b():
    x = ff.find_element_by_css_selector('span')
    return x
def c():
    x = ff.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
    return x
```

When I run this, it says that `ff` is not defined, obviously because the a,b,c functions can't access the webdriver.

How do I do this without having to start a webdriver session every time the a,b,c functions are run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Python (indeed, basic programming). If a function needs access to something, you need to pass it:

```
result = options[name](ff)
```

and

```
def a(ff):
    x = ff.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
    return x
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the webdriver library (selenium) and declare the webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.add_argument("window-size=1,1")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\XXX\chromedriver')
```

and then you can use:

```
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
```